# Get branch into which pull request is made

Tags: git

Given the name and ID of a Pull Request, how can I find out into which branch it should be merged?

For instance let's say I have a branch `release1` and another branch `feature/someFeature`. To merge the second branch into the first, let's say I create the pull request `pull/59`.

The problem I have is that I am writing a Jenkins script and I don't know into what I am merging. I don't know if it's `release1`, `release2`, `master` etc.

In this example, can I find out `release1`, given that I know `pull/59`?

**EDIT**

My server is Bitbucket.

Comment: What is your git server? github? gitlab? bitbucket?

Comment: Bitbucket. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy.

Read this excellent tutorial which will explain to you exactly what you need to do.

https://christiangalsterer.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/continuous-integration-for-pull-requests-with-jenkins-and-stash/

You will have to install several plugins and the required parameters are passed in the url from bitbucket to Jenkins.

#### For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?
       url=${PULL_REQUEST_TO_SSH_CLONE_URL}
       &branches=pr/${PULL_REQUEST_TO_BRANCH}
       &sha1=${PULL_REQUEST_FROM_HASH}
       &PULL_REQUEST_URL=${PULL_REQUEST_URL}
       &PULL_REQUEST_ID=${PULL_REQUEST_ID}
```

and there are many other parameters as well.
You need to install addon for bitbucket and plugins for Jenkins.
All is described in the above article.

Comment: So I'm not using that functionality from the UI. I am using the `pipeline` plugin which allows me to make a script for all this. I don't understand where the above URL fits in.

Comment: And I don't really understand from the articles nor from your answer how is any of this connected to finding out the destination branch. Sorry, I am new to this DEVOPS stuff and I'm probably missing many things.